# While generating RDLC report in API service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rdlc

I get this error while generating a `.RDLC` report in ASP.NET Core:

> AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing.;An error has occurred during report processing.
>
> Culture is not supported. (Parameter 'culture')
> 4096 (0x1000) is an invalid culture identifier.
>
> AspNetCore.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing.
> Culture is not supported. (Parameter 'culture')
> 4096 (0x1000) is an invalid culture identifier.
> System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported. (Parameter 'culture')
> 4096 (0x1000) is an invalid culture identifier.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
> at AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
> at AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
> at AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalReport.Execute(RenderType renderType, Int32 pageIndex, Dictionary`2 parameters, String findString) at Web_Project.Services.ReportService.GenerateReportAsync() in D:\NET-POS\WEB-API\Price-Checker-API\POS-APP-API\POS-APP-WEB-API\Web-Project\Services\ReportService.cs:line 64 at Web_Project.Controllers.ReportsController.Generate(String reportName) in D:\NET-POS\WEB-API\Price-Checker-API\POS-APP-API\POS-APP-WEB-API\Web-Project\Controllers\ReportsController.cs:line 43 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

**HEADERS**

```
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 192.168.0.64:7223
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/121.0.0.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Referer: http://192.168.0.64:7223/swagger/index.html
```

Comment: Error is a Swagger Error and doesn't like the Accept-Language "en-US, en; q=0.9"  See https://github.com/fenomeno83/SwaggerGlobalization